# Spring REST Controller returns JSON with empty data

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I have a simple Spring Boot web application. I'm trying to receive some data from server. The Controller returns a collection, but the browser receives empty JSON - the number of curly brackets is equals to the number of objects from server, but its content is empty.

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeManagerImpl employeeManagerImpl;

    @RequestMapping(path="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        Iterable<Employee> employeesIterable = employeeManagerImpl.getAllEmployees();
        return employeesIterable;
    }
}
```

The method fires and a browser shows:

[image]

Nothing more in the console. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1723798766434132067L;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter 
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Getter @Setter
    private BigDecimal salary;

    public Employee(){

    }
}
```

Comment: please provide `employeesIterable ` here

Comment: We need to at least see the code for the POJO. It might be that you don't have any serializable fields.

Comment: Use ResponseBody with the return type as  public @ResponseBody Iterable<Employee> getAllEmployees() {

Comment: @KaranVerma `@RestController` annotation already takes care of that.

Comment: As is usually, it started after I asked you there. I removed lombok annotations and added common getters and setters. Now i'm receiving what I wanted. But why it doesn't work with lombok?

Comment: Well, there could be numerous possibilities - most probable is that Lombok is not properly configured. Can you call the getters/setters in your code? After building your app are the getters/setters included in the `Employee.class` file?

Comment: Yes, IDE (sts) can see methods, I can call them

Comment: Add getter setter in your model / pojo. It will work !

Comment: Still getting this issue today. Nothing suggested here worked. Ideas welcome

Comment: basically you need public Getters and Setters in your Entity class. Thats the issue I see here

Answer (score 12):

I think you should use Lombok as class level instead of field level.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor    
public class Employee implements Serializable {}
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: I didn't know I can use them at class level. Nice, I will use that, but not in this case... nothing has changed.

Comment: It worked with Data. Then I switched Data with annotations that it covers: ToString, EqualsAndHashCode, Getter, Setter and RequiredArgsConstructor. It worked. Then I only left Getter and Setter. It also worked... I don't get it at all. There must by something wrong with building project by STS then?

Comment: Can you build and run from console as it is?

Comment: the `@Getter` and `@Setter` can be replaced with single annotation `@Data`

Comment: basically you need public Getters and Setters in your Entity class. Thats the issue I see here

Comment: I had the same issue and I resolved it by adding @Getter to my response dto class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a converter in the project that converts JAVA objects to JSON. If not, you need on. Try using Jackson in your project.

Once Jackson jars are imported into the project, the dispatcher servlet should have below:

```
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Spring Boot uses Jackson by default. The problem he experiences about Lombok not generating getters thus the fields are not serialized because Jackson looks for getters.

Comment: @nurgasemetey that is true. This default configuration you are writting about, HARDI, I get for free thanks to spring boot. There's something wrong with lombok getters, I didn't solve this yet.

Comment: Any solution by now? I just stuck into it.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding @ResponseBody to your REST method's return type declaration in the method signature. That should do it if you're using the standard Spring Boot starter project.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The problem is with lombok annotations - they just doesn't work. But why is that?

Comment: `@RestController` automatically adds `@ResponseBody` annotation to all returns.