# Spring REST Controller returns empty JSON. Iterable data structure. Why?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I realize a very similar question was asked and closed because it wasn't specific enough and didn't specify outcomes.  [Closed Off Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914710/spring-rest-controller-returns-json-with-empty-data)

Problem: JSON being returned from REST controller is empty.  Verified data exists and is in the Iterable.

Expected Outcome:  A JSON Array containing objects would be returned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.codeexcursion</groupId>
  <organization>
    <name>Chris Lynch</name>
  </organization>
  <version>1.00.000</version>
  <artifactId>work-tracking</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


  <name>Work Tracking</name>

  <inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id />
      <name>Chris Lynch</name>
      <email>chrislynch42@yahoo.com</email>
      <timezone>-4</timezone>
      <roles>
        <role>Chief cook and bottle washer.</role>
      </roles>
    </developer>
  </developers>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
      <version>10.13.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.codeexcursion.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Entity

```
//Package and import Omitted

@Entity
public class Category {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private Long parentId;

  private String title;

  private String description;

  protected Category() {
  }

  public Category(final String title, String description) {
    this(0L, title, description);
  }

  public Category(Long parentId, final String title, String description) {
    if (parentId == null) {
      parentId = 0L;
    }
    if (title == null || title.trim().isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Title may not be null or empty.");
    }
    if (description == null) {
      description = "";
    }
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id + "; parentId=" + parentId + "; title=" + title + "; description=" + description;
  }


}
```

Resource

```
//Package and import Omitted

@Repository
public interface CategoryCRUD  extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {
  List<Category> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

Rest Controller

```
//Package and import Omitted

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {

  @Autowired
  private CategoryCRUD categoryCRUD;  


  @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<Category> list() {
    System.out.println("findAll");
    categoryCRUD.findAll().forEach((category) -> {
      System.out.println("category=" + category);
    });    
    return categoryCRUD.findAll();
  }

  private List<Category> findAll() {
    final Iterable<Category> data = categoryCRUD.findAll();
    List<Category> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    data.forEach(returnList::add);
    return returnList; 
  }


}
```

Answer (score 22):

I found an answer that was hinted on the closed post but wasn't detailed.  I needed to add getters to my entity.  I expected JPA/Spring to automagically add the getters and setters.  The below fixed my problem.

Entity

```
//Package and imports omitted
@Entity
public class Category {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private Long parentId;

  private String title;

  private String description;

  protected Category() {
  }

  public Category(final String title, String description) {
    this(0L, title, description);
  }

  public Category(Long parentId, final String title, String description) {
    if (parentId == null) {
      parentId = 0L;
    }
    if (title == null || title.trim().isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Title may not be null or empty.");
    }
    if (description == null) {
      description = "";
    }
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id + "; parentId=" + parentId + "; title=" + title + "; description=" + description;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Long getParentId() {
    return parentId;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

}
```

Better answers are welcome.

Comment: If you want getters/setters to be generated automatically, you might want to have a look at project lombok: https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Mate thank you so much ! Worked like a charm. just added getters to my model and that did the trick. so silly to have forgotten!

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the *getters* to the fields of the *entity* were not **public**.

Making them public fixed the issue for me.

Comment: You saved my day. I forgot to add the `getters` in the `entity` class.

Comment: yup, make getters & enjoy.

Comment: for my case, I'm using kotlin, and my data class had private properties.
removing private solved that :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the `lombok` dependency in your `pom.xml` file and you have to setup the `lombok` jar in the IDE you are using (Can be Intellij or Eclipse). if you want to use the annotations `@Data`, it automatically generates the getters, setters and toString() method inside a Java Bean or Pojo class.

You can use `@Getter, @Setter, @AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor` *javadoc* annotation from lombok will generate the getters and setters and constructors for your fields.

Please have a look at this http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok for more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I correct in the understanding that Lombok isn't part of Spring but is a 3rd party library that provides getter and setter annotations?

Comment: Yes, its a thirt party dependency, which is predominantly used in many projects. And if you are using spring boot, you can include it in http://start.spring.io (spring project initializer). Yes it is not a part of Spring framework.